# Error after running makemigrations in django app

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker-compose

I have developed a `django` app and I want to use `postgres` to store some results. For that reason I have the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.2'

services:
 
  elasticsearch:
    container_name: elasticsearch
    build:
      context: elasticsearch/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
        read_only: true
      - type: volume
        source: elasticsearch
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    environment:
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
      ELASTIC_PASSWORD: changeme
    links: 
      - kibana
    networks:
      - elk

  logstash:
    container_name: logstash
    build:
      context: logstash/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./logstash/config/logstash.yml
        target: /usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml
        read_only: true
      - type: bind
        source: ./logstash/pipeline
        target: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
        read_only: true
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
      - "9600:9600"
    expose: 
      - "5044"
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

  kibana:
    container_name: kibana
    build:
      context: kibana/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./kibana/config/kibana.yml
        target: /usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml
        read_only: true
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    networks:
      - elk

  app:
    container_name: app
    build : ./app
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules/ # make node_module empty in container
    command: npm start
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - elk

  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/config:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./nginx/log:/var/log/nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    links:
      - app:app
    depends_on: 
      - app
    networks:
      - elk

  filebeat:
    container_name: filebeat
    build: ./filebeat
    entrypoint: "filebeat -e -strict.perms=false"
    volumes:
      - ./filebeat/config/filebeat.yml:/usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml
      - ./nginx/log:/var/log/nginx
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on: 
      - app
      - nginx
      - logstash
      - elasticsearch
      - kibana
    links: 
      - logstash

  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:13.4
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: backend_db
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    volumes:
      - database-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/ 
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    networks:
      - elk 

networks:
  elk:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  elasticsearch:
  database-data:
```

The relevant with the database part from `settings.py` file is the following:

```
# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases
DATABASES = {
    'default': get_config(
        'DATABASE_URL',
        'sqlite:///' + BASE_DIR.child('db.sqlite3'),
        cast=db_url
    ),
    'postgres': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': get_config('DB_NAME', 'backend_db'),
        'USER': get_config('DB_USER', 'postgres'),
        'PASSWORD': get_config('DB_PASSWORD', 'postgres'),
        'HOST': get_config('DB_HOST', 'postgres-service'),
        'PORT': get_config('DB_PORT', '5432')
    }
}

# Define Database Routers:
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['routers.db_routers.UserRouter', 'routers.db_routers.EventRouter']
```

However, when I run `python3 manage.py makemigrations` I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "postgres-service" to address: Name or service not known


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 19, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 85, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 101, in handle
    loader.check_consistent_history(connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 290, in check_consistent_history
    applied = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 77, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 55, in has_table
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 259, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 235, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "postgres-service" to address: Name or service not known
```

Any idea of what is causing the error?

Comment: AFAIK host name should be `postgres` not `postgres-service`

Comment: @AhmetBurak Even if I change the name to `postgres` I am getting the same error, but with `postgres` instead of `postgres-service`.

Comment: Is there a chance that your container is not able to run? Might be closed unexpectedly and you didn't notice.

Comment: @AhmetBurak No, all services are up and running.